# How make fatal error in build phases script

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftlint

I try make fatal error in lint script. Currently I am able to create a normal bug that allows me to compile the code.
Is there any way to create a fatal error in this script?

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
    swiftlint
else
    echo "error: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode build process fails with an error if a build script terminates with a non-zero exit status:

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
    swiftlint
else
    echo "error: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
    exit 1
fi
```

Alternatively use just

```
swiftlint
```

as build script. If the swiftlint program is not found then the build process  will also fail, with an error message like

```
swiftlint: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```